# How is a article displayed only on Newsfeed? (I DO　NOT want to display on Timeline)

Tags: facebook, feed

I use Graph API
https://graph.facebook.com//feed

The result of having performed API is as follows. 
a. The article is displayed on the user's Timeline.
 
b. The article is displayed on Newsfeed of the user. 
c. The article is displayed on Newsfeed of the user's friends.

but I would like to display only **b** using Graph API.
 (I DO　NOT want to display on Timeline)

Is it possible?
or are there any other good ways?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible via the API, nor can I think of any reason it would become possible in future.